# Why does gradle not recognise a local dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have the following structure:

```
prj
 |
 +-- prj-app1
 |    
 +-- prj-app2
 |    
 +-- other-project
```

my setting.gradle from my `prj` project looks like this:

```
include ':prj-app1'
include ':prj-app2'
include ':other-project'

rootProject.name = 'prj'
```

Now I want to use `other-project` in `prj-app1`. I can use `prj-app2` in `prj-app1` without issue. For this, I added this to the `build.gradle` in `prj-app1`:

```
implementation project(":other-project")
```

However, I cannot import the relevant classes. Building works without issue. Eclipse imports the corresponding class into my code in `prj-app1` when I use a class of `other-project`, but I get the error that the import cannot be resolved.

Now a way which fixed this was to rename `other-project` to `prj-other-project`. Then all worked well. However, since `other-project` is not my project, I cannot rename it as of now. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of changing the order so depends comes first:

```
    ....
    project(":other-project") {
...
    jar {
        enabled = true
        baseName = 'other-project'
        version =  '1.0.0'
    }
    ...
}

project(":prj-app1") {
    jar {
        enabled = true
        baseName = 'prj-app1'
        version =  '1.0.0'
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":other-project")
    }
}
....
```